# Is it possible to run FreeNAS on a Sheevaplug?

Tags: linux, home-server, freenas, dlna, sheevaplug

I recently acquired a Sheevaplug ([this spec](http://www.globalscaletechnologies.com/t-sheevaplugdetails.aspx#features)) and would like to use it for:

1. Storage for my home network
2. Sharing media with home media devices like my TVs

Is it possible to use FreeNAS on the Sheevaplug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SheevaPlug is an ARM processor based product, whereas FreeNAS is only available for x86 and x64 processors.

Having said that, freenas is ultimately a collection of software that allows file and disk volume sharing across a network.

From your description, Samba (file sharing via CIFS - like a Windows share) and/or NFS (linux sharing) would suit your needs, both of which are available out of the box with Sheeva.  So perhaps you don't need freenas.  You could also use [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) to administer it to keep things simple.

If your media serving requirements include DLNA, you can install [Twonky](http://www.plugcomputer.org/plugwiki/index.php/Run_Twonky_Server_on_Sheevaplug) server on Sheevaplug, which is a well used DLNA server.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I require something that's DLNA-compliant, which I understand FreeNAS can be. Disappointing that it's not compatible with my SheevaPlug, though! Thanks for clarifying that for me.

Comment: Updated the answer...